# Making a tree structure in mime data function

Tags: qt, qt5

This is my code for Mimedata function

```
QMimeData *TreeModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList  &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray data; //a kind of RAW format for datas
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QList<TreeItem *> nodes;
    foreach(const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        TreeItem *node = getItem(index);

                  //  Do i make a tree structure here by recursion function for the tree item
        if (!nodes.contains(node))
            nodes << node;
    }
    stream << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();
    stream << nodes.count();
    foreach(TreeItem *node, nodes) {
        stream << reinterpret_cast<qlonglong>(node);
    }
    mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
    return mimeData;
}
```

The issue i am facing is that here i am only able to record the root container and not its childcontainers so when i move or copy this container
in the tree structure only the root container is moved or copied and not its subcontainers.

This is the code for Drop Mime Data

```
bool TreeModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *mimeData, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    //test if the data type is the good one
    if (!mimeData->hasFormat(s_treeNodeMimeType)) {
        return false;
    }
    QByteArray data = mimeData->data(s_treeNodeMimeType);
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    qint64 senderPid;
    stream >> senderPid;
    if (senderPid != QCoreApplication::applicationPid()) {
        // Let's not cast pointers that come from another process...
        return false;
    }
    TreeItem *parentNode = getItem(parent);
    int count;
    stream >> count;

    if (row == -1) {
        if (parent.isValid())
            row = 0;
        else            
            row = rowCount(parent);
    }
    TreeItem *node;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Decode data from the QMimeData
        qlonglong nodePtr;
        stream >> nodePtr;
        node = reinterpret_cast<TreeItem *>(nodePtr);
        if (node->row() < row  && parentNode == node->parent())
            --row;

        TreeItem *nodeNew = new TreeItem(node->GetContainer(), parentNode);
        nodeNew->setContainer(node->GetContainer());


        // Insert at new position
        beginInsertRows(parent, row, row);
        parentNode->insertChild(row, nodeNew);
        endInsertRows();
        ++row;

    }   

    // Remove from old position
    if (QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers() != Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        removeItem(node);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The Header file for treeitem.

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
    explicit TreeItem( Container *data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
    ~TreeItem();
    TreeItem *parent();
    void appendChild(TreeItem *child);

    TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
    int childCount() const;
    int childNumber() const;
    Container data() const ;
    Container* GetContainer();
    bool setData(Container* data , QVariant value);
    void setContainer( Container* data);
    bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
    bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );
    void removeChild(int row);
    void removeChild(TreeItem* itm);
    std::string getChildName(int row);
    std::string getName();
    int row() const;
    void insertChild(int pos, TreeItem *child);

private:
    QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
    Container* itemData;
    TreeItem* parentItem;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By your example code it seems, that you only wanted to drag and drop items inside your application from the same view. Maybe a more simpler approach might fit your application. Just build the following example and consider it as a solution.

It allows you to freely move items and subtrees inside the QTreeView.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto view = new QTreeView;
    auto model = new QStandardItemModel;
    view->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDropMode::InternalMove);
    auto item1 = new QStandardItem("Item1");
    model->appendRow(item1);
    auto item2 = new QStandardItem("Item2");
    model->appendRow(item2);
    auto item3 = new QStandardItem("Item3");
    item2->appendRow(item3);
    view->setModel(model);
    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```